# GET variables with spaces

Tags: php, mysql, string, html

I'm trying to get a variable with spaces. However, the first string is only returned. I tried using `htmlspecialchars`but I did not succeed.

I did:
categories.php
`<a href="categories.php?action=update&category=$category"></a>`

Say, I have a category with the name 'Web Development'.That's two words but whenever I click that link, the status bar only appears to have `categories.php?action=update&category=Web`

How can I get the full string? Thanks

Comment: Use `urlencode`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thanks! It works. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write url parts with spaces try `urlencode()`